# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle: How many students enrolled in a course are ineligible to take it?

Tags: combinatorics

This is the problem I am having issues with

From the 83 students who want to enroll in CS320, 32 have completed CS 120, 27 have completed CS 180, and 35 have completed CS 215, of these, 7 have completed both CS 120 and CS 180, 16 have completed CS 180 and CS 215, and 3 have completed CS 120 and CS 215. Two students have completed all three courses. The prerequisite for CS 320 is completion of one of CS 120, CS 180 , or CS 215. How many students are not eligible to enroll?

I did it and got 25 students are not eligible, I did it before and got 47 are not eligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your attempts resulted in incorrect answers.  The [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) states that

$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$

If we let $A$ denote the students who have completed CS120, $B$ denote the students who have completed CS215, and $C$ denote the students who have completed CS215, then the number of students who have taken at least one of those three courses is 
\begin{align*}
|A \cup B \cup C| & = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|\\
                  & = 32 + 27 + 35 - 7 - 16 - 3 + 2\\
                  & = 70
\end{align*}
Hence, $83 - 70 = 13$ students who signed up for CS320 are ineligible to take the course.